# how do i send an xml file from server to device via http post

Tags: php, xml, http, post

The server will be running php and the device could be iphone or android with its own app to parse the xml sent.
I will send xml as responses to different requests from the app: login, sign in, etc but I have no clue where to start. I`ve googled and googled and answers were about CUrl. Can someone point me in the right direction here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't want to post from the server to the device. You want to read a file off the server. That should be pretty easy, just point the url of the xml file.

Comment: The client application on the device will use xml to get its data. there is no web browser involved in this.

Comment: the client application will need to make an http request to the server to retrieve the xml.

Comment: im tasked with sending xml to the device via http post and i dont know how to do that

Comment: You would not be able to do that without making huge modifications to the device. Even then it would be impractical.

Comment: do you mean the phone will make a call to the server requesting the xml? As far as I know a server cannot post to a device that is not itself a server.

I'm guessing your server will receive a request via a web page request from a phone and your server will respond with the appropriate xml data?

Comment: when a device login, messages for it will be stored in a database and will need to be sent to the device, without any request just a login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. You have to put it into XML content yourself, but this is how you can post from PHP.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#74795

Or you can use curl, but I haven't used it that much yet.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, if you want to POST something from your server, the device also has to be running an HTTP server.  Consider the resource usage this may imply for the device: if it always has to respond to a POST, that may affect its low-power modes, as there will be a background task that must always be running to monitor the port and wake up the server on the device to handle it.

If this is intended to support "push"-style notifications, consider taking a look at the [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) spec instead.

Comment: i see. it is supposed to work like this, a user login, he has messages for him stored in the data base and those message need to be sent to him in an xml. so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: i`ve looked into it, that is new to me. however i have to this in another way, maybe get the client to make a request to see if it got new unread messages.

Comment: I'd recommend having a link on your landing page (wherever the user goes after they log in) that appears if the user has messages.  The user clicks it (making a GET request) and the messages are downloaded.  If that's not possible, then maybe have the client automatically request unread messages as soon as they login.  Or possibly have your app request unread messages whenever it successfully loads a page, unless that would make it too "chatty".

Comment: i agree with your suggestion that after a successful login the client app should auto-request unread messages, thanks for your sugestion